# How to delete nested xml element using qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dom

i have xml file like this

```
<root>
   <element>
       <child id = "0"> Some Text </child> <-- Target To Delete
   </element>
   <element>
       <child id = "1"> Some Text </child>
   </element>
</root>
```

how can i delete child element of id "0" ? using Qt library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
QDomDocument doc;
doc.setContent(oldXml);

QDomNodeList nodes = doc.elementsByTagName("element");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.count(); ++i)
{
    QDomNode node = nodes.at(i);
    QDomElement child = node.firstChildElement("child");
    if (!child.isNull() && child.attribute("id") == "0")
    {
        node.removeChild(child);
    }
}

QString newXml = doc.toString();
```

Comment: thank you, what is "QString newXml = doc.toString();" is it modified xml document in string ? can i write it directly to file ?

Comment: Yes, this string contains modified xml document. Yes, you can write it to a file.